# How to copy files from Ubuntu18.04 drive to Windows drive?

Tags: files, 18.04, lts

I am getting problem while read and write data in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Windows drive... Its usually error-ed of the destination is only read-able.
Anyone can help me to get rid of it.

[image: Error Screenshots]

[after Copying error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70gBn.png)

Comment: If before was booted  windows and after you try to access NTFS volume from ubuntu then you need to fix NTFS File System . Try to use : sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdX1  replace sdX1 with your disk (it's not recommended to use on windows boot many time)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that Windows left the disk in a strange state, and it got mounted "read-only". In a terminal window, you can use:

```
mount | grep "Honey King"
```

to see if it IS `ro`.

Then, to make it `rw`, or to see interesting error messages:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw "/media/$USER/Honey King"
```

Comment: I have applied commands you told above its work half..it error-ed after copying error while creating directory 'example'. I added 1 screen shot above.

Answer (score 0):

The cause it's that you try to access NTFS File System recently used by Windows ( hibernate.sys ).

Quick fix below ( replace sdX1 with your partition where you have that problem  )

**1** **`sudo umount /dev/sdX1`**

**2** **`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdX1`**

**3** **`sudo mount -a`** or **`sudo mount /dev/sdX1 /mnt/mountpoint`**

Keep in mind to replace **/dev/sdX1** and **/mnt/mountpoint** with your own partition or mount point path

To avoid this issue in future you must disable hibernate in windows take a look here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/920730/how-to-disable-and-re-enable-hibernation-on-a-computer-that-is-running